# Windows 10 (Python): I get "geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69" only when I run it from the network. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Windows 10 (Python): I get "geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69" only when I run it from the network.

I am working with geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64 on Windows 7 and 10 workstations. I use it in my automation FrameWork. The Python module that I wrote to handle the FireFox Webdriver holds a network path for the geckodriver.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path='G:\\Python\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe')
```

I prefer to do it this way just for the convenience of maintenance. I have several work stations that run automation scripts and they all manage to handle the FireFox `browser.get(URL)` this way. All except for one Windows 10 work station that shows me the error message (above).
I have tried to define the geckodriver to run locally on it and it manages. But, this is not the solution that I am looking for.

All the other Python libraries that I wrote are found on the same path and I manage to import and run them (with the python interpreter) without elevation. When I elevate the user (Administrator) it doesn't even manage to import my libraries.

I already checked the windows UAC (User Access Control) and it was already set to the minimal level.

What might be the problem ?
Is there some windows 10 security settings that might disturb me ?

Comment: During my investigation I assumed that the fault that I have is related to some Windows 10 security policies. So, I try to execute the geckodriver.exe file locally and from the network path. The result was that locally I managed to run the geckodriver listener. But, I failed to do so when I tried to run it straight from the network path. What I got was the following error: "An invalid argument was supplied. (os error 10022)". What policy do I need to edit in the windows 10 security settings in order to succeed in running the geckodriver from the network path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only after a clean Windows 10 installation the problem was solved

Comment: Unfortunately, a Windows update got me back to where I started. I still don't understand what causes this "OS Error 10022". I have asked for the gecko guys support and they responded by saying that it doesn't look like a geckodriver problem but either an OS problem

Comment: If anyone runs into this error in 2021, try updating geckodriver. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, update (0.29.1 -> 0.30.0) helped in my case. What's interesting 0.29.1 was working fine with Python 3.8 and stopped after switching to 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** Same, error 69

**Solution:** Transfered my geckodriver.exe from my F: drive (Storage & Scripts) to my user folder (C:\Users\UserName\geckodriver.exe) on the  drive.

**Effect:** Worked right away !